# Can I resolve the "single line" formatting of a MySQL Statement?

Tags: mariadb, sql-view, heidisql

I am running HeidiSQL (v10.3.0.5771) against a MySQL MariaDB (v10.1.22) database.

An example query for the purposes of this thread

```
CREATE VIEW vw_TESTVIEW AS
SELECT MONTH
FROM tbl_calendar 
WHERE YEAR = 2016
```

After creating VIEW (like the simple one above) on my computer, I open the editor in Heidi and it's turned it into a single line, like the following, which is a pain, when it comes to maintaining the more complex views.

```
select `tbl_calendar`.`Month` AS `MONTH` from `tbl_calendar` where (`tbl_calendar`.`Year` = 2016)
```

Research suggested that the issue is connected to the ".frm" files, but didn't offer any further help. If I create the view on the server where the database resides, the formatting of the statement is maintained.

On my computer, if I open a query that was created on the server, it's shown in a single line.

**My Assumption**

When opening the code for a VIEW it first attempts to use the information from the FRM file and if that fails, it pulls data from the information_schema. On the server, it has access to the FRM files (as they are in the data folder for the database), whereas on my computer, those files are not accessible, so it keeps falling back to data saved in the information_schema.

Any ideas how I can create the view any maintain the formatting from local installations (as we don't typically work on the server).

**Idea**

When selecting a view, you see that Heidi makes the following two calls, from which we see that the first one resolves to the FRM location (on the server); I wonder if it were possible to change the @@GLOBAL.datadir to be the UNC path of the server and then grant acess permissions to the folder?

```
SELECT CAST(LOAD_FILE(CONCAT(IFNULL(@@GLOBAL.datadir, CONCAT(@@GLOBAL.basedir, 'data/')), 'myDB/vw_testview.frm')) AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8);
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='vw_testview' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='myDB' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

Comment: As the author of HeidiSQL, I'd be interested in any solution here as well. Unfortunately I couldn't find one yet.

Comment: @Anse - I added an additional to the OP, mulling over what I thought "might" be a way forward.

Comment: I guess changing `@@GLOBAL.datadir` to an UNC path will not change anything here. But feel free to test that, this has to be done in the my.ini/my.cnf on your server.

Comment: Are you looking for a SQL pretty-print package?

Comment: @RickJames I was aiming for the SQL statements to appear in the same format as they were, when I created the view (rather than collapsed to one line) as keeping the format that all in-house developers use, makes the queries easier to maintain and develop.

Comment: Sorry, the original text is not available.  OTOH, the revised format can sometimes point out flaws in the original be spelling out defaults.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @Rick, how can a change from a nice human-readable layout to one concatenated line 'point out flaws'? If anything, I would say it introduces flaws.